# A circle tangent to two circles touching internally and line

Tags: geometry, circles

Find the radius of a circle touching two circle $x^2+y^2+3\sqrt{2}(x+y)=0$ and $x^2+y^2+5\sqrt{2}(x+y)=0$ and also touching the common diameter of the two given circles.

The two circles touch internally and the common diameter is $x-y=0$.

Let centre of required circle be $(h,k)$

$$\sqrt{\left(h-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(k-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}=r+3$$

$$\sqrt{\left(h-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(k-\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}=5-r$$

and

$$r=\frac{h-k}{\sqrt{2}}$$

**assuming $h>k$**

Squaring,

$$h^2+k^2+3\sqrt{2}h+3\sqrt{2}k=r^2+6r$$
$$h^2+k^2+5\sqrt{2}h+5\sqrt{2}k=r^2-10r$$
substituting the value of $r$ and subtracting the two equations, 
$$k=\frac{5h}{3}$$

But $h>k$. Where am I making the mistake?

I think there are two such circles which are mirror immages about $y=x$. One of them has $h>k$.

Comment: Clarification: By 'touching' I assume you mean 'tangent to'?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes

Comment: I think you got wrong, after squaring, the sign of the terms with a square root.

Comment: @Aretino Oh no. Thank you. Don't know why I make such mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a diagram based on my understanding of the question.

[image: Circle satisfying tangency requirements of question]